80's Parasite horror movie
This movie was about an upper-middle-class family with a teenage daughter. They hire an attractive young woman as their housekeeper. The woman (housekeeper) quickly starts flirting with the husband causing the wife to get upset and move out. It is found out the woman has an alien and/or demonic parasite in her that's actually in control of the body. It's trying to pass itself over to the teenage daughter for a new body. I remember they somehow kill the parasite in a pool. Plus at the end of the movie you see how the parasite got into the woman by a flashback of a train ride in the late 1800's/early 1900's? 

This sounds very much like The Kiss from 1988, but a few details are a bit off. It's about a model (Joanna Pacula) possessed with a certain parasitical curse that she wants to pass on (with a kiss) to her young niece (Meredith Salenger). So she visits her and tries to seduce her dad. They do defeat her in a pool in the end, but the movie starts with a flashback taking place on a train that shows how she got the parasite as a child. And the mom doesn't leave, she dies in a car accident. Here's the trailer:




P.S. It's possible you've confused the aunt that seduces the husband with an evil housekeeper because there's a couple of movies with a similar plot from that era (like The Hand That Rocks The Cradle and The Guardian).

Yes that's it thank you! It's possible I did mess up some facts to it. Seeing how i only watched it years ago when it came out. Lol

@Taylor No problem. :) Don't forget to mark it as 'solved' with the check mark.
